# Change drawn button to imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a UIbutton that draw it using core graphics inside draw rect:

[image]

I need to redraw it again with UIimageView After the comment :

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if  let  ImageFromCamera = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let ImageView = UIImageView()
        ImageView.image=ImageFromCamera
        ImageView.frame=personalImage.frame
        ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.pickedImage.frame.size.width / 2
        ImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 12.0
        ImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
      //    change the custom drawn button "personalImageButton" to imageView
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still use a button while setting the image and disabling the function

```
personalImageButton.setImage(ImageView, forState: .Normal)
personalImageButton.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to assign somehow UIImageView to UIButton. A possible way to bypass it is to create a transparent button and place it over UIImageView. However in you case it seems you do not need UIImageView at all. Use [setBackgroundImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:) to set button's image and `yourButton.layer` to make it round.

Comment: How to remove the previous  drawn button ?